# How to Show/Hide Fields conditionally in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Help is much appreciated, I am trying to hide a column when its value is empty with the below query.

**Error:**

uncaught exception: Error: command failed: {
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$OpenDate'",
"code" : 168,
"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"

**Document:**

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("60f113b2211038b4b688c3e8"),
        "URN" : 103600,
        "LANAME" : "HTOL",
        "LA" : 311,
        "ESTAB" : 2014,
        "LAESTAB" : 3062352,
        "School_Name" : "Good Day Infant School",
        "Address" : {
                "Street" : "Lodge Road",
                "Locality" : "",
                "Address3" : "",
                "Town" : "London",
                "PostCode" : "CR9 20P"
        },
        "Status" : "Open",
        "OpenDate" : "",
        "CloseDate" : "",
        "MINORGROUP" : "Maintained school",
        "SCHOOLTYPE" : "Community school",
        "ISPRIMARY" : 1,
        "ISSECONDARY" : 0,
        "ISPOST16" : 0,
        "AGELOW" : 3,
        "AGEHIGH" : 7,
        "GENDER" : "Mixed",
        "RELCHAR" : "Does not apply",
        "ADMPOL" : "Not applicable"
}
```

**Query 1:**

```
db.schools.aggregate(
                     [
                      {$project:
                               {OpenDate:{$cond:{if:{$eq:["$OpenDate",""],then:0,else:1}}}}
                      }
                    ]
                   )
```

**Query 2:**

```
db.schools.aggregate(
                     [
                      {
                       $project:
                                {
                                   OpenDate:{ $cond:[{"$OpenDate":""},0,1] }
                                     
                                }
                     }
                     ]
                   )
```

Comment: look at the correct syntax of [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/), your implementation is invalid.

Comment: Have a look if this helpful https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$$REMOVE`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      OpenDate: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $eq: [
              "$OpenDate",
              ""
            ]
          },
          "$$REMOVE",
          "$OpenDate"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/feqod2cFFQu)**